# Search Box Placeholder aligning to left in my way

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Currently my code working fine and aligned to `left` too but i am not satisfied with current alignment.

```css
.text-box-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-box-container>input[type="search"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box-container">
  <input type="search">
</div>
```

I want bring this text to extra left. I mean, in certain position. i will just define it to left in certain position.

How can i do it?

Comment: You want to indent your input-placeholder or your input-text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `.abc` element:

```
.abc::placeholder {
   width: 100% !important;
   text-align: left !important;
   float:left;
   left:0;
}
```

Comment: Should i assign this abc in HTML class too?

Comment: Of course, you should assign this for HTML class with an exact name for clean code. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-indent` property.

```css
input::placeholder {
  text-indent: -15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter text"/>
```